# What do I need to put in jetty.xml to make the admin console work?

Tags: server

I got an ubuntu-server for dev purposes running activemq. I installed them from the package repository and did minor configurations to the activemq. I want to use the admin console but in order to do so I need the webapps folder which seems to be missing from the package.

I searched around in the package and I didn't find any. I suppose that the webapps should be in the `{activemq.home}` folder which is defined from the package on `/usr/share/activemq`. Also I know that it requires jetty configuration as in xml. The jetty config can be found in the example docs: `/usr/share/doc/activemq/examples/conf/jetty.xml.gz`

My question is what should I put into the jetty.xml to make the admin console work? Should I copy the webapps folder from the tar.gz downloaded package from apache site to the home folder?

Posting my current activemq.xml if it's helpful:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true">

    <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                  <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    <vmCursor />
                  </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy> 

        <destinations>
            <queue physicalName="CMAgentStatus" />
            <queue physicalName="CMUpdateRequest" />
            <queue physicalName="CMSnapshotEvent" />
        </destinations>

        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
        </managementContext>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
        </transportConnectors>

    </broker>

<!-- <import resource="jetty.xml"/> -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up downloading the activeMQ binaries from site and install them to /opt/activemq.
Then created the init scripts for activemq and update-rc defaults.

Comment: Great work on figuring this out yourself. You should accept your own answer here (by clicking the tick on the left) so people in the future will know to read this one.